# Hibernate. SQL query. XML mapping

Tags: xml, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

There mapping xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.MyObject" table="OWNER"
           where="service = 462">

        <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null"/>

        <property name="name" column="name"  insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="description" column="description" insert="false" update="false"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class `MyObject` must also contain a set of objects of class`HerObject`:

```
<set name="herObjects" lazy="false">
        <key />
        <one-to-many class="com.example.HerObject"/>
</set>
```

but i need to get `herObjects` using sophisticated sql-query. To do this, pointing out the design (in the example sql simplified):

```
<sql-query name="herObjSQLQuery">
    <load-collection alias="ho" role="com.example.MyObject.herObjects"/>
    <![CDATA[
    select {ho.*} from her_obj ho where owner_id = :id
    ]]>
</sql-query>
```

where instead of `: id` on the idea should be put `id` from current `MyObject`. The unit `set` also added a line:

```
<loader query-ref="com.example.MyObject.herObjSQLQuery" />
```

The result was the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
            <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
                "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

            <hibernate-mapping>
                <class name="com.example.MyObject" table="AAA"
                       where="service = 462 and status = 1 and conference_number > 0">

                    <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null"/>

                    <property name="name" column="name"  insert="false" update="false"/>
                    <property name="description" column="description" insert="false" update="false"/>

                    <set name="herObjects" lazy="false">
                           <key />
                           <one-to-many class="com.example.HerObject"/>
                           <loader query-ref="com.example.MyObject.herObjSQLQuery" />
                    </set>

                    <sql-query name="herObjSQLQuery">
                           <load-collection alias="ho" role="com.example.MyObject.herObjects"/>
                           <![CDATA[
                           select {ho.*} from her_obj ho where owner_id = :id
                           ]]>
                    </sql-query>

                </class>
            </hibernate-mapping>
```

**Where is the mistake? How in the sql-query to substitute the current `id` value from `MyObject`?**